# How to share Flutter iOS App I'm currently developing to friends/investors for testing or reviews on their devices

Tags: ios, flutter

I cannot share **Flutter iOS App** with anyone for testing or reviews unlike with Android where I can share via WhatsApp or any other means to friends and they are able to install

When I use Xcode to archive via **Product->Archive** still nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://firebase.google.com/products/app-distribution.
App distribution is a relatively new feature from Firebase that allows you to distribute pre-release versions of your app to the testers you choose.
I didn't try iOS distribution yet, but you should be able to distribute it to your friends/investors if you add them as testers.

Comment: This exactly what i was looking for, i already managed to distribute both iOS and Android apps.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need an active ios developer subscription to publish your app for testing. You can choose between distribute with Testflight or add the devices UDIDs in your Provisioning Profile, archive and upload your ipa + manifest file to a SSL secured website.